# Update an object and only one, on the display

Tags: shader, webgl, three.js, fragment-shader

I use the librairy three.js to work in WebGL. In my case, I have two objects in my scene, I would like update my objects on the display independtly.
I use shaders to modify the color of my objects, I would like modify the value of a uniform parameter of my fragment shader and apply the shader only on one of my objects. I would like apply a "drawElements" on my mesh and draw it with the new parameter.
When I do "renderer.render( scene, camera );" I update all objects, and it's not what I want.
How can I do this ? Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version prior to version r.53, you need to clone your uniforms for your second shader:

```
shaderB = shaderA.clone();
shaderB.uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shaderA.uniforms );
```

A better choice is to update to the current version, r.53. In that case, the uniforms cloning is done for you, and the following should be sufficient:

```
shaderB = shaderA.clone();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I work with the last realease (version r53).
It's a good idea, so my object have a her own shader but after when I want just re-draw one of then how can I make it? If I use render, I will re draw all of my objects, no ?

Comment: I am trying to understand your question... 1. Is is true that each object has its own shader, and that all shaders are working correctly? 2. Is it true that your want to re-render the screen, but only redraw one of the objects? Do the objects overlap on the screen?

Comment: In fact I try to adapt this code (http://egraether.com/demos/booleans.html) to be compatible with THREE.js.As I said I have two objects and I would like apply a subtraction between them.In this code he uses shaders and makes the booleans subtraction by using GL stencil and depth buffers.Concerning my first question, it was about the objects render which is applied in the example, he redraws each time only one object and not both, in a specific order with some modifications to create the subtraction.I meet some difficulty to adapt this code with three.js and particulary to redraw only 1 object.

Comment: Would you consider a different approach using Constructive Solid Geometry? See this [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2111#issuecomment-6532836)

Comment: I know this library, currently we use it but booleans operations take many time with complex objects.

Comment: Have you tried `renderer.render( scene1, camera )`, `renderer.render( scene2, camera )`, with one object in each scene and `renderer.autoClear = false`?

Comment: But if i have two scenes, objects can't interact and I can't apply a subtraction between them. No ?

Comment: Your original question did not have all these additional constraints... If you still want to pursue this using three.js without CSG, you are going to have to post a live demo along with a question containing all the relevant information. It is just too hard to help you in the abstract... It's an interesting problem, though. If you get it working, it would be nice to see it live. :-)